# Issue with angularjs to call http get service

Tags: java, angularjs, rest

i am trying to do simple http get with angular. i am using eclipse and jboss.

i already have following rest service
`/gestionDechets/library/dechet/getRandomDechet`

which returns:
`{"idDechets":7,"difficulty":1,"name":"toto","category":"test"}`

now when i try to call it with angular it does not work.

here is my code:

get.js

```
angular.module("mainModule", []).controller("mainController", function ($scope, $http)
  {

$scope.getCallJSON = function () {


  $http.get('/gestionDechets/library/dechet/getRandomDechet')
      .success(function(data) {
        $scope.dechet = data;
    });
};
})
```

get.html

```
<body ng-app="mainModule">
<div ng-controller="mainController">
<button ng-click="getCallJSON()">GET call</button><br />
<textarea class="logTextArea">{{dechet}}</textarea>
</div>
</body>
```

Nothing happens when i click on GET call button.

What is wrong in this ?

Note: first answer to correct REST path done but issue still persists

Comment: Did you verify if the call goes through and comes back (Check your network console) fine without any http errors? Do you see data in the success callback?

Comment: i tried and here what i found in console 
Methode GET
En cache Non
État OK
Code 200

it seems to work, but result is not displayed in test area. what is problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the wrong REST service from  your code. Compare your question comment to your code

```
/gestionDechets/library/dechet/getRandomDechet
```

Versus

```
 $http.get('/gestionDechets/library/dechet/retrieveDechet')
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, i updated code but still nothing returns in text area after click on GET call button.